# Lift instance of class with a `MonadIO` type-variable to the transformed monad

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers, lifting

As part of a program where I need to log data from monadic computations, I am trying to define a class to make this more convenient.

```
module Serial where
import Data.Int
import Data.IORef
import System.IO
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.Marshal
import Foreign.Storable

class MonadIO m => Serial m a where
    get :: Handle -> m a
    put :: Handle -> a -> m ()
```

One of the things I'd like to be able to do is to define `get` and `put` in a 'higher' monad, since some data is inaccessible in `IO`. For simpler data, like instances of `Storable`, for example, `IO` is enough. I'd like to keep the basic instances in the 'lowest' possible monad, but allow the actions to be lifted to any 'higher' `MonadIO` instance.

```
instance (Serial m a, MonadIO (t m), MonadTrans t) 
    => Serial (t m) a where
       get = lift . get
       put h = lift . put h

instance Storable a => Serial IO a where
    get h = alloca (\ptr 
        -> hGetBuf h ptr (sizeOf (undefined :: a))
        >> peek ptr)
    put h a = with a (\ptr 
        -> hPutBuf h ptr $ sizeOf a)
```

The idea is to enable functions like

```
func :: Serial m a => Handle -> a -> m ()
func h a = put h (0::Int32) >> put h a
```

where an instance in `IO` can be combined with an instance in any `MonadIO`. However with my current code, GHC cannot deduce the instance for `Serial m Int32`. For the particular case of lifting `IO` this problem can be solved by `liftIO`, but if the base type is `t IO` that doesn't work anymore. I think this can be solved by overlapping instances, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just add `Serial m Int32` to the constraints of `func`? Seems like the right thing to do here.

Comment: It works... why did I not think of that? Should I answer the question myself, or do you want to?

Comment: The super-polymorphic instance of `Serial` for `t m` will land you in overlapping territory immediately. Better to use `DefaultSignatures` to give default definitions based on that idea.

Comment: Something like `default get :: (m ~ t n, MonadTrans t, Serial n a) => Handle -> m a` with a default definition of `get = lift . get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write out the required extra constraint:

```
func :: (Serial m a, Serial m Int32) => Handle -> a -> m ()
func h a = put h (0::Int32) >> put h a
```

(I think this requires `-XFlexibleContexts`.)

If this makes the signatures unwieldy, you can group together constraints in a “constraint synonym class”:

```
class (Serial m a, Serial m Int32, Serial m Int64, ...)
       => StoSerial m a
instance (Serial m a, Serial m Int32, Serial m Int64, ...)
       => StoSerial m a

func :: StoSerial m a => Handle -> a -> m ()
func h a = put h (0::Int32) >> put h a
```