# Is there a way to polymorphically lift instances of a class with a monad type variable, without overlapping instances?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers, overlapping-instances

This question can be considered a follow-up of

[Lift instance of class with a `MonadIO` type-variable to the transformed monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184067/lift-instance-of-class-with-a-monadio-type-variable-to-the-transformed-monad)

Which provides an example of an application of where this would be used.

The idea is that a typeclass

```
class (Monad m) => Class m a where
  method :: a -> m ()
```

exist, with base instances in different monads

```
instance Class M A where 
  method = undefined

instance Class (T M) B where
  method = undefined
```

. What I want is a way to lift any instance to itself, or higher in the transformer stack, much like what `liftIO` does for `IO`. My initial Idea was to define a lifting instance

```
instance (MonadTrans t, Class m a) => Class (t m) a where
  method = lift . method
```

This has the problem however of creating overlapping instances when more than one transformer is applied, as `lift` is polymorphic, and can be replaced by, for example, `lift . lift`.

It was suggested to instead use a similar default instance,

```
class (Monad m) => Class m a where
  method :: a -> m ()
  default method :: (m ~ t n, MonadTrans t, Class n a) => a -> m ()
  method = lift . method
```

that can then be used to declare lifting instances

```
instance (MonadTrans t) => Class (t M) A

instance (MonadTrans t) => Class (t (T M)) B
```

. This works, but lifting instances need to be declared for each base instance, so I am curious; is there any other way to solve this without resorting to overlapping instances?

Comment: Why do you need a `Class (T M) B` instance in the first place? Can't that case be covered by `(MonadTrans t, Class m a) => Class (t m) a` ?

Comment: Or is the idea to limit `T M` to only `B`, but disallow the use of `A` with `T M`?

Comment: The idea is that the implementation of `method` for `B` is in `T M`, and is impossible to define in just `M`.

Comment: @notBob Can we assume that the set of base instances is "closed", that is, not extensible by users of the library?

Comment: @danidiaz No, this can not be assumed. While I will likely be the only user of it, I intend to keep only the most general stuff in this module and define instances in other modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

> ```hs
> instance (MonadTrans t) => Class (t M) A
> instance (MonadTrans t) => Class (t (T M)) B
> ```
>
> This works, but lifting instances need to be declared for each base instance[....]

That's not how those defaults are intended to be used. The instances should look like

```
instance Class m a => Class (StateT s m) a
instance Class m a => Class (MaybeT m) a
```

and so on.